# Angular 2 subscribe from component or service?

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

#### Context

I have a component `HospitalComponent` that tries to show a list of hospitals. It uses the `readAll` method from the `HospitalService` (that returns an Observable from firebase) :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.hospitalService
    .readAll() // Make a firebase call
    .subscribe(hospitals => this.hospitals = hospitals);
}
```

The route `/hospital` is plugged to this component `HospitalComponent`. Each time I reach `/hospital`, Angular 2 make a new `HospitalComponent`, and a new call is made to the `hospitalService`.

#### Problem

Each time I reach `/hospital`, the hospital list is showing with delay.

#### Question

Is it a good practice to retrieve the hospital list from the service constructor itself ? This way, I can manage the refresh list from background, instead of having some delay. I would have in the component :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.hospitals = this.hospitalService.readAll();
}
```

and in the service :

```
constructor(private hospitalService: HospitalService) {
  hospitalService.subscribe(hospitals => this.hospitals = hospitals);
}
```

But this implies to manage manually all hospital changes ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From a technical viewpoint both "solutions" are pretty much equal - since they basically do the same thing it is up to your personal taste if you just want to conside your two solutions.

But in general: Try to **avoid manual subscriptions** at all.

There are a couple things that you can improve (the following code is based on the assumption, that you'd rather show an outdated list, that is updated in the background than to show a loading-indicator):

- try to avoid manual subscriptions (especially(!!) in components) -> use the `async`-pipe instead
- try to avoid stateful components (even services if possible) -> use streams instead

Your Service

```
export class HospitalService {
    allHospitals$: BehaviorSubject<IHospital[]> = new BehaviorSubject<IHospital[]>([]);

    // the fetchAll() method can be called in the constructor, or somewhere else in the application e.g. during startup, this depends on your application-flow, maybe some login is required ect...
    fetchAll(): Observable<IHospital[]> {
        const fetch$: Observable<IHospital[]> = ...get_stuff_from_firebase().share();
        fetch$
            .do(allHospitals => this.allHospitals$.next(allHospitals);
            .subscribe();
        return fetch$; // optional, just in case you'd want to do something with the immediate result(or error) outside the service
    }
}
```

Your component (=> just inject the service)

```
constructor(private hospitalService: HospitalService) {
    // nothing to do here
}
```

The template of the component (=> the async-pipe automatically manages the subscription and unsubscribes automatically as well, so you don't have to worry about memory-leaks ect...)

```
<div *ngFor="let hospital of (hospitalService.allHospitals$ | async)">
    {{hospital.name}}
</div>
```

---

A fourth(but much more extended) solutions would be to use a central store like [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store) - So with ngrx basically the part of `allHospitals$` would be moved to a centrally managed store-module and you would strictly divide up your application, so that a service will do *nothing but fetching and processing* data, the store will do *nothing but storing and emitting* data and a component will do *nothing but displaying* data.

Comment: Okay, but is there a strategy when I need to group the fetched results in some way and sort them before displaying them in the Component? Just having the `Observable`s won't help, isn't it?