# In Angular where to subscribe in service or in component & why?

Tags: angular, service, subscribe

This question is very common, some prefer to use in service some in component:

[Angular 2 subscribe from component or service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021487/angular-2-subscribe-from-component-or-service): it says never do the manual subscription means from component!

If we don't want any data then why we need to subscribe(in service)? and when the unsubscribe will be called?

If we are subscribing from component:

```
 this.serviceA.getMethodObservable().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
 });
```

Note: Subscription is never unsubscribed!

If Observable could not complete by its own, then whole component, template and all associated objects, will live in memory forever.

For this we use

```
 // onDestroy: subject
 this.serviceA.getMethodObservable()
   .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy))
   .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
 });

 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy.next();
 }
```

It is a question to discuss in detail and understand the pros and cons any approach!
So my question is WHICH ONE & WHY?

Comment: Isn't the choice between `async` pipe in the html and manual subscription in the component? Only in exceptional cases would you subscribe in the service - not as standard - surely?

Comment: I subscribe in the components because I get access to the `onDestroy` hook like you have. I can also take advantage of the `async` pipe in component's `html` where it does the subscribing and unsubscribing for you. Services are long lived and having a subscription there seems bad for me.

Answer (score 7):

In short:

- **Subscribing in a service:** not really useful since a service is designed to hold a state, share this state and notify about state changes. A service is not designed to react to a state change
- **Subscribing in the component:** unsafe when the `Observable` never completes and you don't manually unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook
- **Let the framework subscribe for you** (e.g: with `async` pipe). Safe because no risk of hanging subscriptions causing memory leaks. You can still expose a `pipe`d `Observable` to the template and perform various operations on component level thanks to the rxjs operators without risking any memory leak (even if the callbacks refer to `this`)

Comment: we can use the async pipe whenever we want to display the data in the TEMPLATE file.
How do we handle the other operations like POST, PUT and DELETE without subscription?

Comment: If you use the `HttpClient` the return values are regular `Observable`, they can be suscribed with the `async` pipe like any other `Observable`. Just store the resulting `Observable` at component level instead of subscribing to it.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVellingiri I solved that by using a `submitting$` observable that's subscribed to in the template via `| async` for things like spinners. 

Another observable is derived from this and fires an http request when it's true to fetch the data and when complete it emits a false. The template is obviously subscribed to this for data. 

When the button is clicked, just call `submitting$.next(true) and your spinners, http request, etc all 'react' to that w/no manual subscriptions. You can do all this in you constructor as you don't need the angular lifecycle hooks.